# Match word in PHP regex to not include

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I want to fetch `<FONT COLOR="#0000ff">(insert some text here)<\/FONT>` with preg_match. Lines similar to that are repeating and touching each other, so if I try something generic like `<FONT COLOR="#0000ff">(?<NAME>+)<\/FONT>` it'll fetch all of them as one cell. So I threw on `[^<]` to make it stop at the first less than it encountered, thus keeping it from including HTML and therefore being one cell...

However, the text I'm fetching sometimes contains HTML that I want. Is there a way to use `[^]` with `</F`? My attempts at a negative look ahead did not work because it goes "yep, there's definitely a closing font tag on the end. Better not return anything."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need a RegEx to perform non-greedy match. Eg,

If query string is: `<x> abc </x> <x> def </x> <x> hig </x>`

Our RegEx is: `/<x>(.*)<\/x>/`

Then a greedy match is performed and what is returned is the whole query string because it satisfies the RegEx. To avoid it we use, non-greedy matching.

New RegEx: `/<x>(.*?)<\/x>/`

It should return all three tags with `preg_match_all()`

Comment: That was simpler than expected, but exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.